# Given a equivalence relation in a probability space we want to show events $A_1$,$A_2$ are equivalent if $P(A_1 \cap A_2) =\max\{P(A_1),P(A_2)\}$

Tags: probability

> Let $(\Omega,\beta, P)$ be a probability space. The events $A_1, A_2$ are equivalent in this probability space if $P(A_1 - A_2) \cup P(A_2 - A_1) = 0$. Show that if $A_1, A_2$ are equivalent then $P(A_1 \cap A_2) = \max\{P(A_1),P(A_2)\}$.

My approach to this problem is that maybe we just need to show $P(A_1 - A_2) \cup P(A_2 - A_1) = 0$ is equivalent to  $P(A_1 \cap A_2) =\max\{P(A_1),P(A_2)\}$. Would this be the correct approach? Intuitively this argument makes sense to me . If we have $P(A_1 - A_2) \cup P(A_2 - A_1) = 0$ wouldn't that imply  $P(A_1 \cap A_2) = 0$? But I think there might be a mistake in my thought process here since $\max\{P(A_1),P(A_2)\} \neq 0$ is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If we have $P(A_1 - A_2) \cup P(A_2 - A_1) = 0$ wouldn't that imply  $P(A_1 \cap A_2) = 0$?

No, for example if $A_1=A_2=\Omega$.

Since $\mathbb P(A_1\cap A_2)\leqslant\mathbb P(A_1)\leqslant\max\{\mathbb P(A_1),\mathbb P(A_2)\}$, we only have to show that $\mathbb P(A_1)\leqslant\mathbb P(A_1\cap A_2)$ and $\mathbb P(A_2)\leqslant\mathbb P(A_1\cap A_2)$. Why would this be true? We know that the measure of $A_1\setminus A_2$ and $A_2\setminus A_1$ are $0$. Recall that 
$$\mathbb P(A_1)=\mathbb P(A_1\cap A_2^c)+\mathbb P(A_1\cap A_2).$$

Answer (score 2):

Since $$0\leq P(A_1\ominus A_2)=P(A_1/A_2\cup A_2/A_1)\leq P(A_1/A_2)+P(A_2/A_1)=0$$ we can conclude
$$P(A_1\ominus A_2)=0$$
where $\ominus$ is symmetric difference.

On the other hand,
$$P(A_1\ominus A_2)=P(A_1\cup A_2)-P(A_1\cap A_2)=0$$
which implies
$$P(A_1\cup A_2)=P(A_1\cap A_2)$$
or
$$A_1=A_2  \ \ \text{(up to a set of probability 0)}$$

Then of course
$$P(A_1\cap A_2)=P(A_1)=P(A_2)=\max\{P(A_1),P(A_2)\}$$